# Opencv cpp process different part of same video with multithread

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I use only one videocapture in 5 different thread? and process them at the same time?

What I am doing now is I am using 5 video capture in 5 threads. However, the processing time is longer than executing the video linearly in one thread. I want to process a 10 minutes video in 2 minutes(divide 10minutes video into 5 threads).

Is there any better suggestion?

---

Update:

I did it by allocating huge memory space to an array and store matrix in that array temporary. It is very memory consuming and in the end I store video frames in jpg file and call it when I need it. The latter is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab frames by the same `VideoCapture` object but process frames in multiple threads. A very simple example is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

void blur(cv::Mat &image) {
  cv::GaussianBlur(image, image, cv::Size(7,7), -1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout<<"VideoCapture did not open"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frames[2];
    std::thread tds[2];

    while(true) {
        if(!cap.read(frames[0]) || !cap.read(frames[1]))
        {
            std::cout<<"Frames empty"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

        tds[0] = std::thread(&blur, std::ref(frames[0]));
        tds[1] = std::thread(&blur, std::ref(frames[1]));

        tds[0].join();
        tds[1].join();

        cv::imshow("Frame", frames[0]);
        if ((cv::waitKey(30) & 0XFF) == 'q')
            break;
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this viable if I have a video of 2 hours (more than 200k frames)? In this code, the total number of threads is proportional to the total number of frames right

Comment: @VivianYeoh You can launch as many threads as you want. But keep in mind that your processor can handle a limited amount of threads.

Comment: still think it's not really efficient. But thank you for telling me that